# Drobo has become read only and can't be changed

Tags: permission

My Drobo that acts as my media server and Time Machine host for my family's Macs has become read only. While this would normally be a nuisance, it's become a real problem in that I can't change it back from the Get Info Window I've also tried chmod +w to no avail. Any hints on what to do?

In the attached photo, you'll see that the options are dimmed and say that I should have access, but the disk is still read only.

[Get Info Window](http://www.evansbrasfield.com/images/askdiff/ReadOnly.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest following the official support guide for this issue available here:

http://support.drobo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42/~/why-is-my-drobo-storage-device,-connected-to-my-mac,-suddenly-read-only-and

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problems. I'd restarted a number of times but had not physically unplugged the unit.

Answer (score 0):

what did you do? did you use disk warrior? this has happened to me now, Nov 2013 on Drobo 5D. Disk warrior did not work and so Im having to move all my work over. A real pain. I hate drobo now.  drobo got me to purchase Disk warrior so down 80£ and still had to buy extra drives to move all this work off it.

Comment: Should this be a comment on the answer from Lyken or perhaps an edit to the question?